# OS X Server kills WiFi connection

Tags: macos, continuous-integration, wifi, osx-server

After OS X Server installation my MacBook can't connect to WiFi network. I don't know how to fix this problem. I tried two different machines with different systems (10.10.3 and 10.10.4) and server versions (4.1 and 5.0). If I delete OS X Server everything is fixed again.

Comment: Are you on an enterprise PEAP Wifi network by any chance?

Comment: Yes, I'm on an enterprise network.

Comment: I never found a solution around this. My enterprise network issues host certificates (viewable in keychain) when authenticating to get on the wifi via PEAP (MSCHAPv2). OS X Server also creates its own host certificates. For some reason, these conflict and a certificate mismatch error starts appearing on console.app, preventing wifi authentication. My workaround was to run the server offsite.

Comment: Thank you for your response anyway. Maybe I need to ask Apple directly because this issue is very annoying.

Comment: Do you resolve that issue?

Comment: The same here!!! I'm on an enterprise network.